# Css not loading causing the dashboard not loading correctly

Tags: css

The error in question is as follows:

Refused to apply style from 'mysite/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/crm-menubar.e7a0463626d3eb2004ca8b83b4b12bad.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Open your browser's Developer's tools - eg in Firefox, go to the menu, choose Web Developer, then Network.  Reload the page and then look at the content returned for that css utl.  I'm guessing it shows an error page rather than css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this by resetting the css path in the settings.
It was trying to access an folder that didnt exist.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Drupal.  I needed to run composer civicrm:publish

Best,
Josh